# How to remove substring starting with RT and ends with ":"

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with a column consisting of tweets. Some tweets are retweets, which start with `RT @username: ....`. I would like to remove this part of the string while keeping the string that comes after it.

See the example below:

```
stringsExample <- c("RT @WhiteHouse: Yesterday, President Biden...",
 "During World War II...")
```

The results I want are: `Yesterday, President Biden...` `During World War II...`

Comment: Simply `gsub('.*: ', '', stringsExample)`

Answer (score 2):

Replace anything that starts (regex `^`) with "RT" followed by one or more characters (regex `.+?`), until a colon ":" with empty space "".

```
gsub("^RT.+?: ", "", stringsExample)

[1] "Yesterday, President Biden..." "During World War II..."
```